# Analytics for PHP not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Kindly look the below URL

https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/server/php/#analytics%20for%20php

```
Segment::track(array(
  "userId" => "f4ca124298",
  "event" => "Signed Up",
  "properties" => array(
    "plan" => "Enterprise"
  )
));
```

I implemented the above code in

> /var/www/html/exams/wp-content/themes/startertheme/functions.php

in wordpress directory but it is not working. Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm please:

After, You need to require the Segment.php file into your functions.php file.

```
require_once("/path/to/analytics-php/lib/Segment.php");
```

Comment: Yes i have done like this require_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/segment_io_php/segment_io_php/lib/Segment.php"); . The segment class calling correct. after require is pasted this below code class_alias('Segment', 'Analytics');

Comment: class_alias('Segment', 'Analytics');
Segment::init("YOUR_WRITE_KEY");  is configured ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine now. Paste the below code `Segment::flush();` in each function like below.

```
function login_event() {
    Segment::track(array(
          "userId" => "NO USER ID",
          "event" => "Login event"
        ));
    Segment::flush();
}
```